# Avoid auto-period character after quick type space in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I've noticed that in Sublime Text 3, that if I type a word and then double-space quickly after I'm done entering the word in, it automatically places a period after the word

Something like

`obj` + two `spacebar` keystrokes

will result in

`obj.`

I've looked through the preferences and I see all the `auto_complete` keys, but even with auto completed disabled, Sublime persists in added that period.  How can I disable this behavior in Sublime?

Comment: I'm not aware of any default functionality in Sublime that does anything like this. It sounds more like either something a plugin is doing, or something e.g. a tablet computer is doing. I'd try temporarily reverting to the default state of Sublime to see if it happens there or not.

Comment: @OdatNurd The culprit was a package I had installed via the Package Manager.  Specifically it was Markdown Preview.  I'll add an issue on [its github repo](https://github.com/revolunet/sublimetext-markdown-preview).  Thanks for suggesting to look into plugins!

Comment: @OdatNurd I wrote too soon.  The issue appears to have returned.  I should mention that I'm seeing the behavior on macOS sierra.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/251531/macos-two-spaces-to-input-period-full-stop

Answer (score 182, accepted):

It's a macOS feature that was [added with Sierra](https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/macos-sierra-add-period-double-space/)

It can be disabled globally via `System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Text` and unchecking `Add period with double-space` as per the article instructions.

Quite a handy feature for most things but was driving me to distraction trying to edit `.md` files!

Comment: Note that this is in the *Mac* keyboard setting itself, nothing to do with sublime. It took me a few minutes of trying what's in this answer before realizing this, so hopefully I can save someone else some time :)

Comment: MacOS Ventura? Go to `System Settings -> Keyboard -> Text Input -> Edit...` and uncheck the option: "Add full stop with double-space"

Answer (score 7):

In addition, you can also disable this with the Terminal by executing:

`defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSAutomaticPeriodSubstitutionEnabled -int 0`

If you want to enable it, pass `1`.

Comment: Only got this after the update to Sonoma. It was adding those in the regex replace of all things. This is god-awful, thank you for the fix.

Answer (score 2):

FYI: this option may also be called "[Add full stop with double-space](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh27071/mac#:%7E:text=Add%20full%20stop%20with%20double-space)"

Still at: System Preferences > Text

Comment: I believe it's localized to "full stop" or "period" depending on your locale.

Answer (score 1):

in macOS Sonoma Version 14.1.2:

[image: Disable it]